# fromJSON not Updating ViewModel Knockout.js from differnt viewModel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I am making a call from one view model (viewModel1) to refresh my data inside a different view model (viewModel2).

```
**viewModel1**.fire = function () {
     $.getJSON("Post", function (result) {
     ko.mapping.updateFromJS(**viewModel2**.employees, result);
});
}
```

I am about to give up on this one is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Using the right methods always helps: `updateFromJS` doesn't exist. Try `ko.mapping.fromJS`.

Comment: niether work I did try that.. Why would someone down vote my question.